# How to disable automatic HEAD on express?

Tags: node.js, express

From [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html):

> The app.get() function is automatically called for the HTTP HEAD method in addition to the GET method if app.head() was not called for the path before app.get().

It means that if you register `HEAD` method after `GET` for the same path, it will not be called. And I can't just switch the order because I have some automation on top of express which is responsible for registering the routes, so I don't control the order in which the routes are registered.

**Is it possible to disable this feature? How?**